# how to include or require a view into another view MVC

Tags: php

I want to create a page that will act as a sidebar on all pages. This sidebar shows some widgets which should get records from the database. I don't want to have to copy and paste this sidebar code into every single other view but rather want to require or include it.

I am not sure how to go about this but what I tried was:

- Created a folder in the views folder called "widgets" and put an
  index.php file in it.
- Created a Widgets.php file in the controllers folder
- Created a Widget.php file in the models folder
- Send the data from the model to the controller and sent to the view.

If I go directly to the index.php file in the widgets view, it works fine and the database records are displayed as I want.

However, if I try and include this index file in another view somewhere else, I get an "undefined index" and "invalid argument supplied foreach()".

So, what is the proper way to achieve this?

PS.I am not using a framework and this is my controller:

```
public function index()
    {

        $widgets = $this->widgetModel->getWidgets();

        $data = [

        'widgets' => $widgets

        ];

        $this->view('widgets/index', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Your getting errors in code we can't see, it isn't easy helping with code we know nothing about.

Comment: @NigelRen, I understand that. But at the same time I didn't want to just paste loads and loads of code and give everyone a headache. I am first looking for advice on the correct principle I suppose and I can post code from there or please let me know if there is any particular code you are looking for and I will gladly post it.